# XML/RSS reader- front or back end?

Tags: xml, web

I'm a newbie to web development and am working on a feed aggregator using Python Django framework. The way I'm trying to do it is to have a table full of URL's linking to rss feeds (like https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss), and give each user the option to subscribe to them.

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    userAccount = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'profile',
        primary_key = True
    )
    feeds = models.ManyToManyField(SubscribedFeed, blank = True)

class SubscribedFeed(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My question was how to handle actually interpreting the xml. Would there any significant difference in using Python to parse, and then serving the extracted data, vs just serving the URL and using JavaScript to parse it client-side? More generally, would this task be better suited for the front-end or back-end? If one is better than the other, why? (speed, simplicity, something else). I apologize if this is a bad question, this is my first time posting one.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb question. You can't do cross origin requests in javascript to get an RSS feed